# Combination probability problem of students picking crayons at random.

Tags: probability, combinations

I am having this problem at the Blaine WSMC competition 2018 test, and I still can't figure this out. The full problem is here:


A classroom of 27 students each have an identical box of 64 uniquely-colored crayons. One at
a time, students choose one of their crayons at random. How many students must choose a
crayon in order for there to be at least a 30% probability that there is a matching crayon?


Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Did you attempt at all? Try solving this via finding first number of classmates for which a probability that each of the students has unique crayons is lesser than 70%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Find the probability of *no* matching crayons after 1 student has chosen. Then after two students have chosen. Then after three students have chosen. Keep going until you reach the desired probability.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't get it, on the answer key it says the answer is 8. However, i just can't figure out how that is the answer :( Thank you for your help.

Comment: @BrianZheng What is the probability of no matching crayons after one student has chosen?

Comment: I think 1/63 is the probability right? If we continue that pattern, after the eighth student chose the crayon, the probability became 1/56, which still doesn't, make 70 percent(since the question requires at least 30 percent chance to have a matching crayon)

Comment: @BrianZheng so what you're saying is that after only one student has chosen a crayon, the probability of no matches among the chosen crayons is $\frac1{63}$? I believe you can see yourself why that's wrong, if you just think about it.

Comment: Oh sorry my bad I think it is 63/64 right? (Correct me if I am wrong :) However, after eight students chose the crayons, the probability became around 85 percent, which still doesn't make sense. Thank you so much for your help though, I will accept this answer.

Comment: @BrianZheng After only a single student has chosen a crayon, how can there possibly be a match among the chosen crayons?

Comment: there is a 1/64 percent chance that there is a match, but how can that help? Thank you.

Comment: @BrianZheng Forget probability for a second, and just think possibility. How can the first student match anything if he is the first one to choose? What other crayons are there that the one he has chosen can match?

Comment: What the first student has chose doesn't matter, after he has chosen, there is a 1 out of 64 crayons that will match that color

Comment: @BrianZheng But that's for the second student. The first student can't match anything, so the probability of no matches present after he has chosen a crayon is $1$. Then, as you say, after student $2$ has chosen a crayon, there is a $\frac{63}{64}$ probability of no matches. Now it's the third person's turn. What's the probability that he draws a crayon that doesn't match the other two?